# What kind of fraction will have this property?

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

List out i/19:

[image]

They form a square, and the sum of each column is the same, 81.

i/7 also have such property:

```
142857
285714
428571
571428
714285
857142
```

Any other fractions have such property?
What kind of fractions will have such property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after numbers that are the decimal period of so-called [cyclic numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number)

$7$ and $19$ in this context are called [full reptend primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_reptend_prime) ([OEIS A001913](https://oeis.org/A001913)):

> Primes p such that the decimal expansion of 1/p has period p-1, which
>   is the greatest period possible for any integer.

The first few are $7, 17, 19, 23, 29, 47, 59, 61, 97.$